# Postgres 9.4: Include sibling column in each jsonb array result

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

If I have a table like this:

```
office_id int
employees jsonb
```

and the data looks something like this:

```
1
[{ "name" : "John" }, { "name" : "Jane" }]
```

Is there an easy way to query so that the results look like this:

```
name,office_id
John,1
Jane,1
```

I've been reading through the [json functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) and it seems like it's possible, but I can't seem to figure it out. I would rather not have to store the office_id on each nested object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_array_elements` to expand the json array

```
select id , json_array_elements(employees)->>'name' from mytable
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9a847/5

Comment: In order to use that, do I need to specify each column independently. For example, if the objects in the array have 5 properties, do I need to use 5 json_array_elements calls?

Comment: @JeremyBaker yes, one json_array_element call per property that you need to select. The result will contain the same number of rows as the number of elements in the json array.