# Postgres 9.4: Include sibling column in jsonb array on SELECT

Tags: json, postgresql

If I have a table like this:

```
office_id int
employees jsonb
```

and the data looks something like this:

```
1
[{ "name" : "John" }, { "name" : "Jane" }]
```

Is there an easy way to query so that the results look like this:

```
office_id,employees
1,[{ "name" : "John", "office_id" : 1 }, { "name" : "Jane", "office_id" : 1 }]
```

For example data, check out this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ac37b/1/0

The results should actually look like this:

```
id  employees
1   [{ "name" : "John", "office_id" : 1 }, { "name" : "Jane", "office_id" : 1 }]
2   [{ "name" : "Jamal", "office_id" : 1 }]
```

I've been reading through the [json functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) and it seems like it's possible, but I can't seem to figure it out. I would rather not have to store the office_id on each nested object.

Note: This is similar to [my other question about jsonb arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717084/postgres-9-4-include-sibling-column-in-each-jsonb-array-result), but the desired output is different.

Comment: Can you provide clearer sample data? `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements? Right now this just looks like `SELECT office_id, employees FROM my_table`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are selecting from a Postgres table or a json object table. Doing a normal query and converting it to json can be done with json_agg().

Here is a normal query:

```
ao_db=# SELECT * FROM record.instance;
                  id                  | created_by |          created_on           | modified_by |          modified_on          
--------------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------
 18d8ca56-87b6-11e5-9c15-48d22415d991 | sysop      | 2015-11-10 23:19:47.181026+09 | sysop       | 2015-11-10 23:19:47.181026+09
 190a0e86-87b6-11e5-9c15-48d22415d991 | sysop      | 2015-11-10 23:19:47.56517+09  | sysop       | 2015-11-10 23:19:47.56517+09
 57611c9c-87b6-11e5-8c4b-48d22415d991 | admin      | 2015-11-10 23:21:32.399775+09 | admin       | 2015-11-10 23:22:27.975266+09
(3 行)
```

Here is the same query passed through json_agg():

```
ao_db=# WITH j AS (SELECT * FROM record.instance) SELECT json_agg(j) FROM j;
                                                                                           json_agg                                                                                           
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"id":"18d8ca56-87b6-11e5-9c15-48d22415d991","created_by":"sysop","created_on":"2015-11-10T23:19:47.181026+09:00","modified_by":"sysop","modified_on":"2015-11-10T23:19:47.181026+09:00"}, +
  {"id":"190a0e86-87b6-11e5-9c15-48d22415d991","created_by":"sysop","created_on":"2015-11-10T23:19:47.56517+09:00","modified_by":"sysop","modified_on":"2015-11-10T23:19:47.56517+09:00"},   +
  {"id":"57611c9c-87b6-11e5-8c4b-48d22415d991","created_by":"admin","created_on":"2015-11-10T23:21:32.399775+09:00","modified_by":"admin","modified_on":"2015-11-10T23:22:27.975266+09:00"}]
```